# iOS / xCode4: can I copy a ViewController complete with all functionality

Tags: ios4, xcode4

This may be a silly question, so forgive me if it is but I'm not a Mac guy and this is my first shot at building a serious app.

I've built a ViewController to display a tableview and data, but my app is made up of several sections which do almost the same thing.  Is there a way to copy it and all the settings so I can then just go and change the minor details without having to reproduce all of the subviews and wire everything up multiple times?

Or am I just being lazy ;-)

Cheers

Comment: An extra view controller for a minor change seems extreme.  Why not simply code the one view controller you have to be abstract in the sense that you can reuse it for multiple purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this in Cocoa is to put all your "copyable" UI/controller assemblies into their own Nib/Xib files. This way, you load a new copy of the assembly each time. See [this article](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000064.php) for the quick and dirty.

This is essentially how NSDocument works (note the separate xib for your document, separate from MainMenu.xib) and even how the prototype view of an NSCollectionView is intended to work.

Once you have your fresh copy of the assembly, you copy your settings (state) into it. "How" depends on how you have your state stored. Keep it all in a convenient place with a convenient setter/getter at the top-level object (the controller that becomes the xib's File's Owner) and you should be able to say `[newController setSettings:[originalController settings]];`.